# What is the difference between the Throw keyword and the ThrowTerminatingError method in Powershell?

Tags: powershell

Is there any difference between using the `Throw` keyword and `$PSCmdlet.ThrowTerminatingError` in a Powershell cmdlet?

I've got a number of cmdlets where I want to rethrow a caught exception and I'm wondering what is the best practice (or correct way) when rethrowing an exception.

The following code gives a minimal example of what I mean:

```
Function My-Cmdlet
{
  [CmdletBinding()]
  Param($msg)

  Try
  {
    Throw $msg
  }
  Catch
  {
    # Do I rethrow using this...
    Throw $_.Exception

    # Or this...?
    $PSCmdlet.ThrowTerminatingError($_.Exception)
  }
}
```

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19285405/3115685) details it well

Comment: You can read more about `Throw` and `$PSCmdlet.ThrowTerminatingError` on powershellmagazine http://www.powershellmagazine.com/2011/09/14/custom-errors/

Comment: @arco444, Yes it does. That's pretty much what I was looking for. Thank you.